# Aggregation / Group By w/ a Sum

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get my head around the whole aggregation framework of Mongo.  I'm kind of a newbie here.

```
 I have the following documents:
 { "col1": "camera", "fps": 1, "lat": 3 },
 { "col1": "camera", "fps": 3, "lat": 2 }
 { "col1": "recorders", "fps": 9, "lat": 7 }
 { "col1": "cell", "fps": 8, "lat": 1 }
 { "col1": "cell", "fps": 4, "lat": 3 }
```

How can I set something up to return the results as:

```
 { "col1": "camera", "fps": 4, "lat": 5 },
 { "col1": "recorders", "fps": 9, "lat": 7 },
 { "col1": "cell", "fps": 12, "lat": 4 },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate(
    { $group : {
        _id : "$col1",
        fps : { $sum : "$fps" },
        lat : { $sum : "$lat" }
    }}
);
```

Check this out!!! http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: The result can be checked-out at http://mongotry.herokuapp.com/index.html#?bookmarkId=52fa9bc3fb5356020093c235

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
    { $group: { _id: "$col1", fps: { $sum: "$fps" }, lat: { $sum: "$lat" }}}
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. From [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/): _Every `$group` expression **must** specify an `_id` field_.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't sure if it was required for `$group` or not.